# Pass one string piece of data from parent component to child. Vue.js 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Hoping someone can see a simple mistake I'm making and help me correct it.

I'm trying to pass one string variable as a prop from a parent to a child. This string reveals itself on a checkbox select. There are three and depending which is selected, the name associated will be passed.

Basically, showing some components if different checkboxes are checked. I can clearly see the variable I'm passing shows up in the parent component just fine. I log it out in the method provided. However, it doesn't pass to the child component. I log out there and get undefined as the result.

I've tried multiple solutions, and read about passing props, but nothing is working.

Parent component looks like this.

```js
<template>

  <v-col>
    <v-checkbox
      label="LS"
      color="primary"
      value="ls"
      v-model="checkedSensor"
      @change="check($event)"
      hide-details
    /></v-checkbox>
  </v-col>

  <v-col cols="2" class="mx-auto">
    <v-checkbox
      label="DG"
      color="primary"
      value="dg"
      v-model="checkedSensor"
      @change="check($event)"
      hide-details
     />
   </v-col>

   <v-col cols="2" class="mx-auto">
     <v-checkbox
       label="CR"
       color="primary"
       value="cr"
       v-model="checkedSensor"
       @change="check($event)"
       hide-details
     />

     <ls-sensor v-if="lsSensor" :sensorType="checkedSensor" />

</template>

<script>

  export default{

    data() {
      return {
        checkedSensor: " ",
        lsSensor: false,
        dgSensor: false,
        crSensor: false,
      };
    },

    methods: {

      check: function (e) {
        this.showDeviceComponent(e);
      },

      showDeviceComponent(e) {

        if (e == "ls") {

          this.lsSensor = true;
          this.crSensor = false;
          this.dgSensor = true;

          console.log("file input component", this.checkedSensor)

        } else if (e == "dg") {

          this.dgSensor = true;
          this.lsSensor = false;
          this.crSensor = false;

        } else {

          this.crSensor = true;
          this.dgSensor = false;
          this.lsSensor = false;

        }

      },

    },

  }
</script>
```

Child component (just putting the script here as I don't have it's place in the template yet. In the mounted method, I should be seeing the value from the prop. It's showing up as undefined. Gahh.. what silliness I have made a mistake on?  Your help is greatly appreciated.

```js
export default {

   props:['sensorType'],

   data() {
     return {
       coating: false,
     };
    },

    mounted() {
      console.log("required input component, sensor type", this.sensorType)
    },

    components: {

      coatings: require("@/components/shared/FormData/Coatings.vue").default,
      "ls-sensor-panel": require("@/components/shared/FormData/LS_SensorPanel.vue").default,
    },
  };
```

Comment: if you only have one model which has one value then you should probably use [v-radio](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/radio-buttons/), I cant really see from your code how it goes from string `  ` to `undefined` though, but if its simply not showing it might be because when the check one it fires the event on all the others which then perhaps simply doesn't show it due to which order the stack effects the value

Comment: also seems if you use multiple checkboxes with the same model then its going to be an array not a string https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/checkboxes/#model-as-array

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I had wondered if the check event somehow lets the parent component see it fine, but maybe the lifecycle hooks get screwy and don't pass it correctly? I'm taking wild guesses here

Only one gets selected though on the checkboxes.. once that happens the others don't get touched. Would they still need to be in an array?

Comment: not sure, though id refactor the code to use `<component :is="checkedSensor" />` and make the value on the checkbox to set which component to use (`input-value="ls-sensor"`) then use v-bind to add different props, it would save doing all the boolean switching

Comment: @LawrenceCherone appreciate your help. I found my issue. I was doing everything right when passing the prop down, but what I glossed over was I had another component in the middle of these two. That's where the prop was being sent. A big ol Homer "doooohhhh" came out. I'll post my response below

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that stands out to me is when you create camel cased property names, I am pretty sure that those have to be written as `dash` (-) separated attributes on a component?

```js
<ls-sensor v-if="lsSensor" :sensor-type="checkedSensor" />
```

So `prop: ['sensorType']` is passed as `:sensor-type=""`

Comment: You're definitely right there. I came across that same thing yesterday. That would have popped up had I not found that and fixed it along with my oversight. Which led to this problem. Silly me. I simply missed what I had done and why this was happening.